# Android Device doesn't appear online in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-debug, adb

My device is a Pantech Flex (ATT carrier and rooted)
It will not show up in ADB device chooser

```
I have created a file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
I have created a file /etc/udev/rules.d/50-android.rules
I have created a file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules
I have edited the file ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

I am running eclipse ADT.  I am using ubuntu 13.04

The contents for each of the files are identical (idVendor 10a9 for Pantech):

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that one of those files fixed the problem after a reboot.
No harm in having all of these files if you arnt sure which one your system needs. Its ugly but it works:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
/etc/udev/rules.d/50-android.rules
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules
~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```